# Host a .net Core API on tcp with JWT

Tags: api, .net-core, jwt, tcplistener

We're currently having a .net Core 2.1 API running on an IIS using JWT. External clients call the api controllers for data requests.

Now they want to add an internal server who can communicate with the api. I got the request to create a TCP Server for the communication, because it's alot faster.
I want to create a small Testserver to evaluate the performance. But...
Is that even possible? Can I create a TCP Server, mapped to the API? JWT is based on http, that's another OSI Layer than tcp with completely different header information. Is JWT there possible? Are there better solutions to communicate with the internal Server, where I can improve the performance?

Comment: How is JWT based on HTTP? JWT a token format. The specification doesn't care about how you get the token from a to b.

Comment: Currently the token is in the http Header. My knowledge about TCP is awfully bad, so I'm not quite sure if I can send the Token in a TCP Header. As far as I know, I will need another approach. As an example, I can read the Token with the IHttpContextAccessor Interface. That won't work if we switch to TCP.

Comment: There is no such thing as TCP header. TCP sends and receives bytes, so you can send anything there, JWT and any other data. You can read about TCP online there is plenty of documentation.